# how to program half hour in php H format?

Tags: php, datetime-format

I've looking over stackoverflow and google for a similar question, but haven't found an answer that fits my problem. I'm still sorry if by any chance i let a duplicate question pass by. Please, I'd appreaciate if you kindly pointed me to it.

My issue is I need to program a schedule which is formatted in H format in php, but now I need to add a half hour and don't know how. Here is my code so you can understand better what I mean:

```
$time = (int)date('H');

if($time>=24 && $time<6)
{
    //some code...
}
else if($time>=6 && $time<18) //My problem is here, I need it to be 18:30
{
    //some other code...
}
//code goes on for rest of hours of the day
```

i tried changing $time into (int)date('H:i'), but when i write 
    if($time>=6:00 && $time<18:00)
I get an error because of the ':'

**EDIT:** ok i tried it both ways, here's what the code looks like

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
    if (!isset($timestamp)) {
        $timestamp = time();
    }
    $dw = date( "w", @$timestamp);
    $time = date('HH:ii');

    if($dw>0 && $dw<=4)
    {

        if($time>="00:00" && $time<"04:00")
        {
            $show->current = "A";
            $show->next= "B";
        }
    else if($time>="04:00" && $time<"06:30")
    {
    $show->current = "B";
            $show->next= "C";   
    }
        else if($time>="06:30" && $time<"09:00")
        {
            $show->current = "C";
            $show->next= "D";
        }
```

And it keeps going until it reaches 00:00 again. Problem is this way it doesn't seem to recognize at all the date, so if for example I edit current C time to start at 06:00 instead of 06:30, it doesn't update on my site.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
    if (!isset($timestamp)) {
        $timestamp = time();
    }
    $dw = date( "w", @$timestamp);
    $time = date('G');


    if($dw>0 && $dw<=4)
       {

        if($time>=0 && $time<4)
        {
            $show->current = "A";
            $show->next= "B";
        }
    else if($time>=4 && $time<6.5)
    {
    $show->current = "B";
            $show->next= "C";   
    }
        else if($time>=6.5 && $time<9)
        {
            $show->current = "C";
            $show->next= "D";
        }
```

Here it updates fine, but it doesn't recognize 6.5 as 6:30, so at that time instead of getting as current the C show, i continue getting B.

Comment: You'll have to get the minutes from the date object as well, as you can't compare half an hour to a value that only returns full hours.

Comment: @adeneo I'm sorry i don't understand. You mean change
$time = (int)date('H:i')
I did that, but I get a syntax error at the conditional.

Comment: Using `date("HH:ii")` returns the hour- and minutes-part twice (e.g. it would return `0606:3030` instead of `06:30`. Use `date("H:i")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting `$time` to an integer, that's why it doesn't work.
Try:

```
$time = date('H:i');     // <-- without the "(int)" part

if (($time >= "00:00") && ($time < "06:00")) {
    //some code...
} else if (($time >= "06:00") && ($time < "18:30") {
    //some other code...
} else {
    //code goes on for rest of hours of the day
}
```

**EDIT**:
Make sure to prefix hours between 0 and 9 with a zero, e.g. use `06:...` instead of `6:...`.
(Thx to Marc B for the heads-up).

**EDIT2**:
According to the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) regarding the format characters `H` and `i`:

```
#    format
# character   Description                                    Returned values 
#         H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros   00 through 23
#         i   Minutes with leading zeros                     00 to 59
```

So, expect values from `00:00` to `23:59` in $time (not for example `24:00`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know I had to put the "24:00" between comas.

My problem is that when I replace it that way in my entire code, for some reason it doesn't work and doesnt recognize the schedule (i didn't write the original code). Do you know a way I can add that half hour without changing the rest of the code? (Something like juuga's answer below).

Comment: I suppose you refer to the quotes (`"`). It is basicaly a string so you have to enclose it in quotes (either 'single' or "double"). If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted" :)

Comment: This will fail anyways. you're comparing strings, so `11:00` is going to evaluate as evaluate as **LESS** than `6:00`, because `'1' < '6'`.

Comment: @Marc B: Fixed that. Thx for the heads-up. (Second time I feel embarrassed today :P)

Comment: I'm sorry this still didn't work, site's schedule gets all mixed up when I try it

Comment: Try the updated answer (change `24:00` to `00:00` (obviously)). If it doesn't work, please report some sample input and the (unexpected) results so we can track it down :)

Comment: After commenting on your updated answer, I realized that the error I was commenting about had been copied from _my_ answer (fail). I fixed `HH:ii` changing it to `H:i`. Really sorry for that. Time for me to call it a day I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare the half-hour times directly, you'll have to convert the `hh:mm` into a numerical format, e.g.

```
# 6:45
$hours = 6 + (45 /60); # represent as fractional hours
$minutes = (6 * 60) + 45; # represent in minutes only.
```

and then you can simply do direct comparisons:

```
#    6am            6:30pm
if (($hours > 6) && ($hours <= 18.5))
if (($minutes > 360) && ($minutes < 1125))
```

Comment: Oh i can write 18:30 as 18.5? That was so helpful, i had thought of that but didn't know I could do it.

Comment: I'm sorry I feel silly for asking this, how do I convert date('H') into a numerical format? Just realized it's not working.

Comment: use `G` instead. that's a 0->23 instead of 00->23 format. PHp will auto-convert to int as needed, as long as it LOOKS like an int.

Comment: It's not recognizing as half hour when I write 18.5
I'll keep trying to see if i can find the error

Answer (score -1):

H returns only the hours. You will need to get a separate value of minutes with $minutes = date('i'). Add the $minutes to your elseif with

```
if($time>=6 && ($time<19 && $minutes < 30) )
```

Edit:
as Marc B pointed out, this will fail in cases where $time is more than 6, less and 19 but minutes are more than 30, for example, 7:45 (a valid time).

The solution should be as Expert System suggested. Using date("Hi") or (int) date("Gi");

If the $minutes is wished to be used, then an OR clause should be further added. So something like

```
if( $time>=6 && ($time<18 || ($time == 18 && $minutes < 30)) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your code 

    $time<19 && $minutes < 30

is the same as 18:30 ?

Comment: this will fail. What about `7:45`?

Comment: @MarcB you are absolutely correct, I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: I tried it out and it worked for 18:30.  @MarcB Could you explain the problem please?

Comment: @Ant100: consider 7:45. by juuga's rules, the 7 is properly larger than 6, but 45 is also larger than 30, so the comparison fails, even though 7:45 does fall within 6:00 and 19:30.